# Restrict access to a private content of Strapi via socket with public user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, strapi

The project is about an online quiz system that has questions. I need to send questions by socket to a user if the user has *Authenticated JWT*. So far I have not implemented any authentication method to other pages, where I receive and submit the JWT.
In Strapi Admin Panel I have added the `question` content type as only visible or requestable by authorized users. But when it comes to the socket (not the HTTP request),
[Strapi](https://strapi.io/) does not give any warnings or errors for the user which should not see them, neither warns me anyhow. The magic line of code which requests a question is:

```js
socket.emit('hello', {message: await strapi.services.question.findOne()});
```

I have used a code from the [bug report](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5869#issuecomment-664803469), they have figured out how to communicate with a client-side using `socket.io`. We have to write our custom code in the `bootstrap.js` file of the headless CMS.

> An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before your application
> gets started.
> This allows you to set up your data model, run jobs, or
> perform some special logic.
> See more details here:
> https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/configurations.html#bootstrap

Here is my `bootstrap.js file`:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = async () => {
  process.nextTick(() =>{
    var io = require('socket.io')(strapi.server);
    io.on('connection', async function(socket) {

      console.log(`a user connected`)
      // send message on user connection REQUESTING Questions Collection
      socket.emit('hello', {message: await strapi.services.question.findOne()});

      // listen for user diconnect
      socket.on('disconnect', () =>{
        console.log('a user disconnected')
      });
    });
    strapi.io = io; // register socket io inside strapi main object to use it globally anywhere
  })
};
```

Here is my client side on React frontend:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:1337";

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on('hello', (msg, cb) => {
      console.log('SOCKET HI')
      console.log(msg.message)
      setResponse('sinav icerigi: ' + JSON.stringify(msg.message))
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        Response is:
      </p>
      <p>
        {response}
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

### **The question**: Need you to show me the way I could safely receive and use JWT authentication using Strapi's functions as much as possible.

Strapi settings of Public User:
[image: Strapi public user settings]